# Slow python turtle program

Tags: python, performance, python-turtle

I was trying to make this snake game (no food yet) by using turtle. At length of 1 it still fast but as it goes longer it runs slower and slower.

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SIZE = 500
GRID_NUM = 20
GRID_SIZE = SIZE // GRID_NUM

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SIZE, SIZE)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setworldcoordinates(10, 8, SIZE + 2, SIZE)

class Snake:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = init_turtle()
    self.head.setpos((GRID_SIZE // 2 + GRID_SIZE * 9, GRID_SIZE // 2 + GRID_SIZE * 10))
    self.body = []
    self.direction = 0 # 0 = left, 1 = up, 2 = right, 3 = down
    self.speed = 100 * len(self.body) if len(self.body) > 0 else 100

  def levelup(self):
    if len(self.body) == 0:
      self.body.append(self.head.clone())
    else:
      self.body.append(self.body[len(self.body) - 1].clone())
    
  def update(self):
    for i in range(len(self.body) - 1, -1 , -1):
      if i == 0:
        self.body[i].setpos(self.head.pos())
      else:
        self.body[i].setpos(self.body[i - 1].pos())
  

def init_turtle():
  turtle = Turtle()
  turtle.shape('square')
  turtle.shapesize(1.25)
  turtle.color('red')
  turtle.pencolor('#404040')
  turtle.speed('fastest')
  turtle.up()
  return turtle
def init_border():
  def border():
    turtle = init_turtle()
    for _ in range(4):
      turtle.down()
      turtle.forward(SIZE)
      turtle.left(90)
      yield(0)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.hideturtle()

  def horizontal():
    turtle = init_turtle()
    for x in range(GRID_SIZE, SIZE, GRID_SIZE):
      turtle.goto(x, 0)
      turtle.pendown()
      turtle.goto(x, SIZE)
      turtle.penup()
      yield(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()

  def vertical():
    turtle = init_turtle()
    for y in range(GRID_SIZE, SIZE, GRID_SIZE):
      turtle.goto(0, y)
      turtle.pendown()
      turtle.goto(SIZE, y)
      turtle.penup()
      yield(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()

  generator1 = border()
  generator2 = horizontal()
  generator3 = vertical()
  while(next(generator1, 1) + next(generator2, 1) + next(generator3, 1) < 3):
    pass

def start_game():
  snake = Snake()

  def pop():
    snake.body.pop()
  def right():
    snake.direction = 0
  def up():
    snake.direction = 1
  def left():
    snake.direction = 2
  def down():
    snake.direction = 3
  def exit():
    screen.bye()

  screen.onkey(pop, 'q')
  screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
  screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
  screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
  screen.onkey(down, 'Down')
  screen.onkey(exit, 'Escape')
  screen.onkey(snake.levelup, 'Return')
  screen.listen()

  while True:
    snake.update()
    snake.head.setheading(snake.direction * 90)
    snake.head.forward(GRID_SIZE)
    print('snake', snake.head.pos())


init_border()
start_game()
screen.mainloop()
```

At first i think the cause of the problem was defines a lot of function but i don't know. Also i am new to python so i don't know any kind of optimizing methods.

Any ideas to optimize this program?

Comment: I tried to test what you have described, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look at. I see no snake, only console output, which does not seem to get slower over time. (edit: I see, after pressing "Enter" a few times it does get slower)

Comment: In `update()` you move every part of `body`, so this is going to take longer, the more parts there are. Maybe you can only move one part and leave all others where they are?

Comment: @mkrieger1 is right. I Timed your code and your `update` function takes too long. You should move only the last part of the body to the first place, next snake position.

Comment: I see now, let me try that approach. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

We can speed up long snakes by doing the drawing off screen and sending explicit updates.  Below is a rework of your code that does just that and includes a temporary patch to make the snake move in a square so you can just hit  to see how much the snake is affected by additional body segments:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SIZE = 525
GRID_NUM = 20
GRID_SIZE = SIZE // GRID_NUM

RIGHT, UP, LEFT, DOWN = range(4)

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = init_turtle()
        self.head.setpos(GRID_NUM//2, GRID_NUM//2)
        self.direction = LEFT
        self.body = []

    def levelup(self):
        if self.body:
            self.body.append(self.body[-1].clone())
        else:
                self.body.append(self.head.clone())

    def update(self):
        for i in range(len(self.body) - 1, -1, -1):
            if i == 0:
                self.body[i].setposition(self.head.position())
            else:
                self.body[i].setposition(self.body[i - 1].position())

def init_turtle():
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.shape('square')
    print(GRID_SIZE)
    turtle.shapesize((GRID_SIZE - 1) / 20)
    turtle.color('#404040', 'red')
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.penup()

    return turtle

def init_border():
    def border():
        turtle = init_turtle()

        turtle.goto(-0.5, -0.5)

        for _ in range(4):
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.forward(GRID_NUM)
            turtle.left(90)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.hideturtle()

    def vertical():
        turtle = init_turtle()

        for x in range(GRID_NUM):
            turtle.goto(x - 0.5, -0.5)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(x - 0.5, GRID_NUM - 0.5)
            turtle.penup()
            yield 0

        turtle.hideturtle()

    def horizontal():
        turtle = init_turtle()

        for y in range(GRID_NUM):
            turtle.goto(-0.5, y + 0.5)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(GRID_NUM - 0.5, y + 0.5)
            turtle.penup()
            yield 0

        turtle.hideturtle()

    border()
    generator1 = horizontal()
    generator2 = vertical()

    while next(generator1, 1) + next(generator2, 1) < 2:
        pass

def start_game():
    snake = Snake()

    def right():
        snake.direction = RIGHT

    def up():
        snake.direction = UP

    def left():
        snake.direction = LEFT

    def down():
        snake.direction = DOWN

    screen.onkey(snake.body.pop, 'q')
    screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
    screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
    screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
    screen.onkey(down, 'Down')
    screen.onkey(screen.bye, 'Escape')
    screen.onkey(snake.levelup, 'Return')
    screen.listen()

    while True:
        snake.update()
        snake.head.setheading(snake.direction * 90)
        snake.head.forward(1)

        # Run snake around in a square for testing purposes
        x, y = snake.head.position()

        if round(x) == 1 and snake.direction == LEFT:
            up()
        elif round(y) == GRID_NUM - 2 and snake.direction == UP:
            right()
        elif round(x) == GRID_NUM - 2 and snake.direction == RIGHT:
            down()
        elif round(y) == 1 and snake.direction == DOWN:
            left()

        screen.update()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SIZE, SIZE)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setworldcoordinates(-0.75, -0.75, GRID_NUM + 0.25, GRID_NUM + 0.25)

init_border()

screen.tracer(False)

start_game()

screen.mainloop()  # never reached!
```

I'd recommend both approaches as the main loop will only get more complicated (slower) as you add food and border detection.

I changed your coordinate system to make it *snake centric*.  That is, `forward(1)` moves one square on the grid rather than having to do the math.  If you're going to mess with the coordinates anyway, why not tweak them to your best advantage.